# Collabnet Subversion upgrade path from version 1.6.2 - using FSFS format

Tags: svn, subversion-edge, fsfs

We use Collabnet Subversion and are on version 1.6.2, with FSFS format repository. On Windows 2003 server.

Can I upgrade to Subversion Edge and still keep my existing FSFS repositories?

I'm hoping that the answer is an "obvious yes", but I can't find that answer anywhere. Thanks.

P.S. I asked this in serverfault, as it is not really a programming question, but have not received and answer in 2 days, hence the question to the "real" developer community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. There are no changes in the server side (but to be sure check the change logs about it). With edge you mean the 1.6.X line to the top-most release (1.6.12).

Comment: Thank you, khmarbaise, I'll take your word for it.  I'm probably just being paranoid, but thought I should just make sure.